# Identify what terminal a ruby script is running in

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a gem that utilizes SGR codes. There are discrepancies between terminals that I've found myself. E.g. `\e[2m` makes faint text in Ubuntu's `gnome terminal`, but `\e[2m` does nothing in Windows 8.1's `Command Prompt With Ruby`. So my ruby program needs to know what terminal it is running in and from there, utilize (or not utilize) certain sgr codes.

Is there a magic bullet, in pure ruby or **hopefully with a gem**, for finding out what terminal we're running in? And I mean any terminal, no matter how exotic. I'd love be able to do this, depending on the terminal we're running my gem in (This is pseudo-code, `MagicBullet` is a class belonging to the gem I'm hoping you'll refer me to):

```
MagicBullet.identify #=> ['gnome-terminal', '6.3.2']
```

Or:

```
MagicBullet.identify #=> ['konsole', '4.5']
```

Or:

```
MagicBullet.identify #=> ['command-prompt', '13.37']
```

Or:

```
MagicBullet.identify #=> ['NeWT', '15.2']
```

[image: terminal info window]

Is there a a sure-fire way to find out regardless of OS...this information feels so readily available...maybe a gem that looks for a range of OS signals/processes that belong to a list of known terminals, something like that. I've tried `ENV['TERM']`, and while that returns `:xterm` in a gnome-terminal, I'd prefer it to return `:gnome-terminal`. In `Command Prompt With Ruby` it returns `nil`, which isn't very helpful considering all non-linux (I think) terminals will return `nil`. Of course, I could run `if !ENV['TERM']` and then utilize a different set of logic to find the terminal's name, but that doesn't feel "sure fire" to me. It'll probably fail with other "exotic" terminals.

So I'd like, as an answer, either:

- A gem that gives a sure-fire way to identify what terminal and what version we're running
- A pure ruby way to give a sure-fire way to identify what terminal and what version we're running
- An algorithm that gives me a pretty good shot at identifying what terminal and version we're running, and I'm talking all flavors of Linux, Sun Microsystems stuff, Apple's operating systems (Terminal and the third-party iTerm are two terminals for Apple's operating systems for example). Anything that MRI can be installed on.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93376/which-terminal-type-am-i-using

Comment: Flagged as off topic, because you are asking for a gem (library), a tutorial, or some sort of software to solve your issue.