# Identify a specific process

Tags: ruby, operating-system

I'm thinking of creating a gem that can return the type of terminal we're currently running, be it `Ubuntu`'s `gnome terminal` or `Window`'s `Command Processor`. Let's call this gem "Identifier" in this question.

I want to be able to do this.

In `Window`'s `Command Procesor`:

```
> irb
require 'identifier'
Identifier.identify #=> 'Command Processor'
```

In `Ubuntu`'s `Gnome Terminal`:

```
$ irb
require 'identifier'
Identifier.identify #=> 'Gnome Terminal'
```

Firstly, I would love to know if you have a clever way of finding out this information. Remember, it has to work in:

- Windows 2000 or later
- Linux 2.6+
- FreeBSD
- Solaris 8+
- HP-UX 10+
- OS X 10.4+
- AIX 5.3+

The way I'm thinking of doing it is pretty simple. First, I determine the os with this snippet of pure ruby: `RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']` Then, I utilize the [sys-proctable gem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable) to get an array of all running processes. I then simply check if this array of processes contains a terminal program that is available for the detected OS. This won't be clever, I'll simply need to hardcode every available terminal for Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, HP-UX, OS X, AIX, but still doable. It's a finite list. And if someone's terminal cannot be defined, it doesn't matter. It'll raise an error clearly explaining the problem and a link to the gem's github project directory where they can add their terminal name its process name to the project. Anyway, my idea looks something like this (pseudo code):

```
proc_table = Sys::ProcTable.ps
case RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
when "i686-linux"
    utilized = proc_table & ['terminator','tilda','guake','gnome-terminal','Yakuake','ROXTerm']
when "x64-mingw32"
    utilized = proc_table & ['windows-command-host']
when "some-other-madness"
...
end
```

Now, this should actually work for most cases, but there is one edge case that is bugging me! **What if they have two terminal programs running at the same time? What if gnome-terminal and ROXTerm, for example, are both installed and running?**

Our `utilized` variable would look like this: `['gnome-terminal','ROXTerm']`. *How do we pick which one?* Here's the question...do you have an ingenious way we can somehow manipulate the process in a certain way to identify which process is the terminal that's currently running the script? Or something? If this question gets nothing I'll just tell the user to simply quit the terminal they're not using, but I'd love this to be able to work automatically and I feel it's so possible. The script has been executed from Terminal A, Terminal A and Terminal B are both running...so choose Terminal A! Doesn't seem crazy.

Any ideas? Remember, we are identifying the OS so OS specific hacks are acceptable.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811782/identify-what-terminal-a-ruby-script-is-running-in)

Comment: You don't have to know. You have environment variable TERM and the terminfo database, that should be enough for any practical reasons.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy ENV["TERM"] returns nil in all non-linux OS'. Explain how to get this information regarding terminfo. Do you mean this gem? http://www.a-k-r.org/ruby-terminfo/ This just returns a terminal's screensize. Nothing whatsoever regarding terminal type. I need to know due to SGR dependencies.

Comment: I think TERM should work on any UNIX-ish system, not only linux. Exotic systems like MS Windows have to be identified otherwise... but they are unlikely to support multiple terminal-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about building a branch of a process tree to determine the terminal?

```
require 'sys/proctable'

def process_tree_branch pid = Process.pid
  proc_table = Sys::ProcTable.ps
  by_pid = proc_table.inject({}) do |r, p| r[p.pid] = p; r; end

  result = []

  current = by_pid[pid]
  while current && current.pid != 0 do
    result << current
    current = by_pid[current.ppid]
  end

  result
end

puts process_tree_branch.map(&:cmdline).inspect

# ["ruby example.rb", "-bash", "sshd: vb@pts/0", "sshd: vb [priv]", "/usr/sbin/sshd -D", "/sbin/init"]
```

Comment: seems promising! Could you explain the `inject` line? Also, your terminal doesn't seem to be appearing in your example array? With me, the `2` index returns `gnome-terminal` but with you it's `sshd: vb@pts/0`? I was thinking different OS' would create a different process tree and the terminal name/exe would be at a different index, but there's nothing in yours that looks like a terminal to me... I don't know much about OS', could you explain?

Comment: inject builds a hash array, where pid is the key and the process and struct is the value. my example is run remotely on some vps, where terminal process is not existing at all (so script is running remotely and terminal is local), but for any local terminal that has an ui it will work just fine, as terminal is usually the parent of the running process. Here is the example for my macbook:["ruby example.rb", "-bash", nil, "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal", nil]. Also I changed the source code to deal with kernel tasks which somewhere is the parent of itself.

Comment: Ah yes I see now...hmm in Windows the tree is different again...it's at `1` index:  `"\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe\" /E:ON /K C:\\Ruby22-x64\\bin\\setrbv
ars.bat"`...whatsmore I can't even simply scan the array to find a possible `exe` because in windows, the Explorer.exe is in the array as well! Would you be interested in a bit of collaboration? I think all this gem requires is some OS-centric logic to drill down to the terminal process :)  https://github.com/jaytarka/terminology/blob/develop/lib/terminology/utils.rb